# How to only play selected notes in Logic Pro X?

Tags: logic-pro

Is there a way to tell Logic Pro X to only play selected notes, effectively turning off non-selected notes of the same bars? Such a feature would be useful to listen to specific lines of a multi-timbral track as for example the left hand of a Piano track.

Comment: I assume you mean midi notes that are on the same track?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just mute the notes you don’t want to hear. If there are fewer notes in the left hand, it might be easier to mute all the notes and then unmute the notes you do want to hear.

Here’s how to mute selected notes within a midi region:

- select the midi region in the Tracks area.
- open the piano roll by pressing E.
- make sure the Piano Roll area is highlighted (has a blue surround). If not, press TAB until it is.
- select all notes in the region in the Piano Roll area by pressing CMD-A.
- mute all of these notes by pressing CTRL-M.
- deselect all notes and then select the ones you want to hear. Unmute these by pressing CTRL-M again.

To unmute all notes after you’ve listened through enough, simply select all notes in the region in the Piano Roll again and press CTRL-M twice.

This might sound a little convoluted, but as with all keyboard shortcuts in Logic, it’s really quick with practice. I just got my son to time me; it took 10 secs to do this process with a four bar region.

Comment: Not as simple as I was hoping, but it works!

Comment: When I record piano parts I often do a separate track for the LH and RH. I do this for several reasons: 1) I’m a terrible pianist, so it helps to play parts separately; 2) I can route the low and high parts to different FX or reverbs; 3) I can listen to the lower or higher part on its own; 4) I can route higher or lower material to different STEMs.